# Make Flutter Status Bar Solid

Tags: flutter, android-statusbar

My app doesn't use AppBar, and the content is overlapping with status bar when scrolled. I tried using `AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>`, however it doesn't change anything.

[Overlapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZb7f.png)

My best try is using SafeArea, however it turned Status Bar to grey.

[Grey Safe Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuTOa.png)

Is there a way to maintain the automatic color of status bar, without it overlapping with the content?

Additional Note:
Flutter 1.17.5

My Tree

```
SafeArea
|_ SingleChildScrollView
   |_ Column
      |_ Container
      |_ Container
      |_ Container
```

EDIT: I just realized the automatic color (status bar follow the first container's color) was because it was transparent. I was thinking of making it solid on runtime, and read it from the first colored widget.

Comment: Is running your app in full screen an option?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your `SafeArea` widget with `Container` widget to change the color of the  `SafeArea` widget

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: Container(
    color: Colors.red, /* Set your status bar color here */
    child: SafeArea(
       child: Container(
            /* Add your Widget here */
    )),
  ),
);
```

Another way You can use `AppBar`

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: //widget
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this make other container turned red as well, not just the status bar

Comment: @Vayth try to add `backgroundColor: Colors.white,` in your `Scaffold`

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
    value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.blue, //or the color you prefer
    ),
    child: SafeArea(child: Scaffold(...)),
  );
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the color "automatic"? Like when the container under safer area is red, it turns red without specifying explicitly?

Comment: I noticed this is because the bar is transparent, is there a way to make it solid on runtime or read on another widget color? If not, maybe this is the best approach

Comment: you can use Theme.of(context) and choose the background color of the scaffold or the AppBar for example